# Storing several macros in one command when they start with `\makeatletter`

Tags: beamer, errors, margins

I want to create `beamer` slides but I frequently need to change the margins of my frames using the commands (thanks to [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) for providing the original code)

```
% Page wide frame
\makeatletter
    \def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
    \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
    \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide\relax
\makeatother
```

I tried to store it in a shorter form as follows

```
\newcommand{\framePageWide}{<the code above>}
```

But I get the error "@\Gm does not match its definition"

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}{5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}{5mm}

\newcommand{\framePageWide}{}

\begin{document}

{

% Page wide frame
\makeatletter
    \def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
    \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
    \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide\relax
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Minipages in beamer}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]

        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}  

    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hopefully you placed the `makeatletter` and `\makeatother` **OUTSIDE** of the `\newcommand{\framePageWide}{...}` definition, and not inside the braces.

Comment: Even with that, it does not work

Comment: I confirm what @StevenB.Segletes is saying: if you do `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\framePageWide}{\def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
    \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
    \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
\hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide\relax}
\makeatother` then there is no problem.

Comment: I defined `\framePageWide` without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around it, but then used `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the text itself after the command has been defined. It is merely misunderstanding. I should have placed `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to enclose the new command in the preamble, not at my attempt to call it

Comment: @marmot would you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I believe @StevenB.Segletes has priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I indicated in my original comment, the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` surround the actual definition, rather than surrounding the content of the definition.  That is to say,

**YES:**

```
\makeatletter\newcommand\framePageWide{...}\makeatother
```

**NO:**

```
\newcommand\framePageWide{\makeatletter...\makeatother}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\newlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}{5mm}
\newlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}
\setlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}{5mm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\framePageWide}{%   
    \def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
    \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
    \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
    \hsize\textwidth\relax
    \columnwidth\textwidth\relax
    \hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\framePageWide

% Page wide frame

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Minipages in beamer}

\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]

        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}  

    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `\framePageWide`, one gets

[image]